# Is there an way to search and scrape data for specific keywords?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a newbie in web-scraping. I need to scrape news titles and contents from a website having the keywords "**COVID**" or "**Coronavirus**". But I can't figure how. Also how do I get to the next page using *BS4*? Should I have to use *Selenium*?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to search for words:

```
import re
soup.find(string=re.compile("COVID"))
```

For your second question. You can find all `<a>` tags (hyperlinks) in the page with something like

```
soup.find_all('a')
```

and navigate from there. For more complex webpage navigation I'd suggest looking into framework called Scrapy